default port 5000 for image specifications in .gitlab-ci.yml
In the past I have skipped the port when specifying images in .gitlab-ci.yml.
some-build-job:
  stage: build
  image: server/image:tag

After a new gitlab installation I have to add the port.
some-build-job:
  stage: build
  image: server:5000/image:tag

Is there a place where the default port can be set to 5000 such that it can be omitted in the image name when writing ci scripts as before?
It is a local gitlab installation in an isolated docker network. Is the origin of the problem maybe that ssh access to the registry is not enabled? If ssh access is enabled then the client (i.e. the runner) may be looking at port 443 by default and then the problem would disappear by itself?

Have you tried using the CI_REGISTRY predefined variable in your CI job? Otherwise if you're asking to change the container registry port, again see GitLab's docs here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/packages/container_registry.html#self-compiled-installations

@ahogen, not using the gitlab registry, hence CI_REGISTRY does not apply

if the port is omitted, docker will check :443 and :80 in that order iirc.

@ Chris Becke I can confirm that it checks 443 first when tls is enabled which is the solution I have gone with.
